# IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 3 with size 1

Tags: python, resnet

I m trying to use vgg16,resnet, efficientnetB0 like architecture but I dont know I m getting stuck at the dataset training part. I have around 100 csr detected oct images out of which i have labelled 41 using Label Studio and around 200 normal (non csr) oct images of retina.I am using resnet for my project "detection og cnetral serous retinopathy using dl" this is the code

```
# Resnet50  : Residual Network on Custom Dataset
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os

dataset_path = os.listdir('C:/Users/shilp/Downloads/major project/dataset')

room_types = os.listdir('C:/Users/shilp/Downloads/major project/dataset')
#print (room_types)  #what kinds of rooms are in this dataset

print("Types of rooms found: ", len(dataset_path))


rooms = []

for item in room_types:
 # Get all the file names
 all_rooms = os.listdir('C:/Users/shilp/Downloads/major project/dataset' + '/' +item)
 #print(all_shoes)

 # Add them to the list
 for room in all_rooms:
    rooms.append((item, str('C:/Users/shilp/Downloads/major project/dataset' + '/' +item) + '/' + room))
    #print(rooms[:1])


    
# Build a dataframe        
rooms_df = pd.DataFrame(data=rooms, columns=['room type', 'image'])
#print(rooms_df.head())
#print(rooms_df.tail())


# Let's check how many samples for each category are present
print("Total number of rooms in the dataset: ", len(rooms_df))

room_count = rooms_df['room type'].value_counts()

#print("rooms in each category: ")
#print(room_count)



import cv2
path = 'C:/Users/shilp/Downloads/major project/dataset/'


im_size = 64

images = []
labels = []

for i in room_types:
    data_path = path + str(i)  # entered in 1st folder and then 2nd folder and then 3rd folder
    filenames = [i for i in os.listdir(data_path) ]
   # print(filenames)  # will get the names of all images
    for f in filenames:
        img = cv2.imread(data_path + '/' + f, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)  # reading that image as array
        #print(img)  # will get the image as an array
        img = cv2.resize(img, (im_size, im_size))
        images.append(img)
        labels.append(i)
labels    
# Transform the image array to a numpy type
images = np.array(images)
images.shape   
images = images.astype('float32') / 255.0

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder #, OneHotEncoder
y=rooms_df['room type'].values
#print(y[:5])

# for y
#y_labelencoder = LabelEncoder ()
#y = y_labelencoder.fit_transform (y)
#print (y)

#y=y.reshape(-1,1)
#onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(binary_features=[0])  #Converted  scalar output into vector output where the correct class will be 1 and other will be 0
#Y= onehotencoder.fit_transform(y)
#Y.shape  #(393, 3)
# Create a label encoder
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()

# Encode the class labels
y_encoded = label_encoder.fit_transform(y)

# Now, y_encoded contains numerical labels (0 for CSR and 1 for Normal)
print(y_encoded)
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


images, y_encoded = shuffle(images, y_encoded, random_state=1)

train_x, test_x, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(images, Y, test_size=0.05, random_state=415)


#inpect the shape of the training and testing.
print(train_x.shape)
print(train_y.shape)
print(test_x.shape)
print(test_y.shape)
import numpy as np
from keras import layers
from keras.layers import Input, Add, Dense, Activation, ZeroPadding2D, BatchNormalization, Flatten, Conv2D, AveragePooling2D, MaxPooling2D, GlobalMaxPooling2D
from keras.models import Model, load_model
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.utils import layer_utils
from keras.utils.data_utils import get_file
from keras.applications.imagenet_utils import preprocess_input
import pydot
from IPython.display import SVG
from keras.utils.vis_utils import model_to_dot
from keras.utils import plot_model

from keras.initializers import glorot_uniform
import scipy.misc
from matplotlib.pyplot import imshow

from keras.initializers import glorot_uniform
from keras.layers import Input, Add, Dense, Activation, ZeroPadding2D, BatchNormalization, Flatten, Conv2D, AveragePooling2D, MaxPooling2D, GlobalMaxPooling2D
# Identity Block
# x is input, y=F(x)
# identity block simply means input should be equal to output. 
#  y = x + F(x)   the layers in a traditional network are learning the true output H(x)
# F(x) = y - x   the layers in a residual network are learning the residual F(x)
# Hence, the name: Residual Block.



def identity_block(X, f, filters, stage, block):
    """
   
    Arguments:
    X -- input of shape (m, height, width, channel)
    f -- shape of the middle CONV's window for the main path
    filters -- python list of integers, defining the number of filters in the CONV layers of the main path
    stage -- integer, used to name the layers, depending on their position in the network
    block -- string/character, used to name the layers, depending on their position in the network
    
    Returns:
    X -- output of the identity block, tensor of shape (n_H, n_W, n_C)
    """
    
    # defining name basis
    conv_name_base = 'res' + str(stage) + block + '_branch'
    bn_name_base = 'bn' + str(stage) + block + '_branch'
    
    # Retrieve Filters
    F1, F2, F3 = filters
    
    # Saving the input value.we need this later to add to the output. 
    X_shortcut = X
    
    # First component of main path
    X = Conv2D(filters = F1, kernel_size = (1, 1), strides = (1,1), padding = 'valid', name = conv_name_base + '2a')(X)
    X = BatchNormalization(axis = 3, name = bn_name_base + '2a')(X)
    X = Activation('relu')(X)

    
    # Second component of main path (≈3 lines)
    X = Conv2D(filters = F2, kernel_size = (f, f), strides = (1,1), padding = 'same', name = conv_name_base + '2b')(X)
    X = BatchNormalization(axis = 3, name = bn_name_base + '2b')(X)
    X = Activation('relu')(X)

    # Third component of main path (≈2 lines)
    X = Conv2D(filters = F3, kernel_size = (1, 1), strides = (1,1), padding = 'valid', name = conv_name_base + '2c')(X)
    X = BatchNormalization(axis = 3, name = bn_name_base + '2c')(X)

    # Final step: Add shortcut value to main path, and pass it through a RELU activation 
    X = Add()([X, X_shortcut])
    X = Activation('relu')(X)
    
    
    return X
# Convolutional Block

def convolutional_block(X, f, filters, stage, block, s = 2):
    
    # defining name basis
    conv_name_base = 'res' + str(stage) + block + '_branch'
    bn_name_base = 'bn' + str(stage) + block + '_branch'
    
    # Retrieve Filters
    F1, F2, F3 = filters
    
    # Save the input value
    X_shortcut = X


    # First layer 
    X = Conv2D(F1, (1, 1), strides = (s,s), name = conv_name_base + '2a')(X) # 1,1 is filter size
    X = BatchNormalization(axis = 3, name = bn_name_base + '2a')(X)  # normalization on channels
    X = Activation('relu')(X)

      
    # Second layer  (f,f)=3*3 filter by default
    X = Conv2D(filters = F2, kernel_size = (f, f), strides = (1,1), padding = 'same', name = conv_name_base + '2b')(X)
    X = BatchNormalization(axis = 3, name = bn_name_base + '2b')(X)
    X = Activation('relu')(X)


    # Third layer
    X = Conv2D(filters = F3, kernel_size = (1, 1), strides = (1,1), padding = 'valid', name = conv_name_base + '2c')(X)
    X = BatchNormalization(axis = 3, name = bn_name_base + '2c')(X)


    ##### SHORTCUT PATH #### 
    X_shortcut = Conv2D(filters = F3, kernel_size = (1, 1), strides = (s,s), padding = 'valid', name = conv_name_base + '1')(X_shortcut)
    X_shortcut = BatchNormalization(axis = 3, name = bn_name_base + '1')(X_shortcut)

    # Final step: Add shortcut value here, and pass it through a RELU activation 
    X = Add()([X, X_shortcut])
    X = Activation('relu')(X)
    
    
    return X

# Creating ResNet 50 
#Each ResNet block is either 2 layer deep
def ResNet50(input_shape=(64, 64,1), classes=2):
    """
    Implementation of the ResNet50 architecture:
    CONV2D -> BATCHNORM -> RELU -> MAXPOOL -> CONVBLOCK -> IDBLOCK*2 -> CONVBLOCK -> IDBLOCK*3
    -> CONVBLOCK -> IDBLOCK*5 -> CONVBLOCK -> IDBLOCK*2 -> AVGPOOL -> TOPLAYER

    """

    # Define the input as a tensor with shape input_shape
    X_input = Input(input_shape)

    # Zero-Padding
    X = ZeroPadding2D((3, 3))(X_input) #3,3 padding

    # Stage 1
    X = Conv2D(64, (7, 7), strides=(2, 2), name='conv1')(X) #64 filters of 7*7 
    X = BatchNormalization(axis=3, name='bn_conv1')(X) #batchnorm applied on channels
    X = Activation('relu')(X)
    X = MaxPooling2D((3, 3), strides=(2, 2))(X) #window size is 3*3

    # Stage 2
    X = convolutional_block(X, f=3, filters=[64, 64, 256], stage=2, block='a', s=1)
    # convolutional_block is a function defined above. Convolutional_block have 3 layers.
    #filters=[64, 64, 256] first 64 is for 1st layer and 2nd 64 is for 2nd layer and 256 is for 3rd layer of convultional block   
    # below are the conv layers from convolutional_block function
    #X = Conv2D(F1, (1, 1), strides = (s,s), name = conv_name_base + '2a')(X)
    #X = Conv2D(F2, kernel_size = (f, f), strides = (1,1), padding = 'same', name = conv_name_base + '2b')(X)
    #X = Conv2D(F3, (1, 1), strides = (s,s), name = conv_name_base + '2a')(X)
   
    X = identity_block(X, 3, [64, 64, 256], stage=2, block='b') 
    #X = Conv2D(filters = F1, kernel_size = (1, 1), strides = (1,1), padding = 'valid', name = conv_name_base + '2a')(X)
    #X = Conv2D(filters = F2, kernel_size = (f, f), strides = (1,1), padding = 'same', name = conv_name_base + '2b')(X)
    #X = Conv2D(filters = F3, kernel_size = (1, 1), strides = (1,1), padding = 'valid', name = conv_name_base + '2c')(X)
  
    X = identity_block(X, 3, [64, 64, 256], stage=2, block='c')
    #X = Conv2D(filters = F1, kernel_size = (1, 1), strides = (1,1), padding = 'valid', name = conv_name_base + '2a')(X)
    #X = Conv2D(filters = F2, kernel_size = (f, f), strides = (1,1), padding = 'same', name = conv_name_base + '2b')(X)
    #X = Conv2D(filters = F3, kernel_size = (1, 1), strides = (1,1), padding = 'valid', name = conv_name_base + '2c')(X)


    ### START CODE HERE ###

    # Stage 3 
    X = convolutional_block(X, f = 3, filters = [128, 128, 512], stage = 3, block='a', s = 2)
    X = identity_block(X, 3, [128, 128, 512], stage=3, block='b')
    X = identity_block(X, 3, [128, 128, 512], stage=3, block='c')
    X = identity_block(X, 3, [128, 128, 512], stage=3, block='d')

    # Stage 4 
    X = convolutional_block(X, f = 3, filters = [256, 256, 1024], stage = 4, block='a', s = 2)
    X = identity_block(X, 3, [256, 256, 1024], stage=4, block='b')
    X = identity_block(X, 3, [256, 256, 1024], stage=4, block='c')
    X = identity_block(X, 3, [256, 256, 1024], stage=4, block='d')
    X = identity_block(X, 3, [256, 256, 1024], stage=4, block='e')
    X = identity_block(X, 3, [256, 256, 1024], stage=4, block='f')

    # Stage 5 
    X = convolutional_block(X, f = 3, filters = [512, 512, 2048], stage = 5, block='a', s = 2)
    X = identity_block(X, 3, [512, 512, 2048], stage=5, block='b')
    X = identity_block(X, 3, [512, 512, 2048], stage=5, block='c')

    # AVGPOOL 
    X = AveragePooling2D((2,2), name="avg_pool")(X)

    ### END CODE HERE ###

    # output layer
    X = Flatten()(X)
    X = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='fc' + str(classes), kernel_initializer = glorot_uniform(seed=0))(X)
    
    
    # Create model
    model = Model(inputs = X_input, outputs = X, name='ResNet50')

    return model

model = ResNet50(input_shape = (64, 64, 1), classes = 2)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs = 6, batch_size = 32) 
preds = model.evaluate(test_x, test_y)
print ("Loss = " + str(preds[0]))
print ("Test Accuracy = " + str(preds[1]))

#*******************this section

from matplotlib.pyplot import imread
img_path = 'C:/Users/shilp/Downloads/Dataset-20230901T201235Z-001/Dataset/CSR14.jpeg'
img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(64, 64), color_mode="grayscale")
x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
x = preprocess_input(x)
print('Input image shape:', x.shape)
my_image = imread(img_path)
imshow(my_image)
print(model.predict(x))
```

but "this section" code after running is giving this error
IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 3 with size 1

please help

i tried to made some few changes but the error is still showing

Comment: too much code, please reduce to this:
[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: is the question referring to the `matplotlob` part at the end ?  if so, it would be better to reconstruct a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in this way:  [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Can you please attach the interpreter output? also the error might be `preds[1]` here. check if `preds` have enough elements to access 1st index.